# Регулярные выражения Кратность

Tags: php

Как с помощью регулярного выражения проверить кратно ли число 100 числу 1000?

Comment: Наверно так: `if(100 === (100 % 1000))`.

Comment: @And, `1000 % 100 === 0`?

Comment: $val = 150/100; if(is_float($val)) echo 'true'; вот это в регулярке как проверить?

Comment: То есть чтобы число не было дробным, а было целым

Comment: А зачем вам в регулярке ? `if(! (150%100)) {}`

Comment: @Visman, а разве, не той-же самой суммы числа - проверяется кратность указанной суммы числа, в данном случае 100? Хотя с другой стороны я с вами согласен, если число кратное, будет `0 === 100 % 1000`, будет не кратно, а вот если сравнить с 100, будет кратно.